# GCP Api Gateway is it possible to update the code of a config file or do I need to create a brand new config every time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, api-gateway

I'm trying to set up API Gateway to work with a GCP Function that I have running.

I previously created a config using the following code in terminal:

```
gcloud api-gateway api-configs create apigateway-gcpfunction-config \
  --api=my-api --openapi-spec=apigateway_gcpfunction_config.yaml \
  --project=my-project --backend-auth-service-account=my-service-account@blah.com
```

This works correctly, and when I view my config using the following code I get a notification that it's active:

```
gcloud api-gateway api-configs describe apigateway-gcpfunction-config --api=my-api --project=my-project
```

However now I'm trying to update my config file because I needed to change the path for my GCP Function, but I can't find anything in the documentation for how to update the code.

I see in [this article detailing updating api-configs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/api-gateway/api-configs/update) that it's possible to update various attributes of a config, but I can't figure out how to update the code itself? Is this impossible? Should I just create a new config every time and relaunch a new gateway with a new config every time there's an update to the config file????

Comment: Furthermore: Do I need to delete and recreate the config every time if I want to keep the same config name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this documentation on [updating an API config](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/creating-api-config#updating-an-api-config):

> You cannot modify an existing API config other than to update its labels and its display name.

It is also stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/api-gateway/api-configs/update) that you provided under **Description**:

> NOTE: Only the name and labels may be updated on an API config.

As of the moment, we could only [create a new API config](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/creating-api-config) if we want to update our config file.

We could file for a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for this option to be available in the future.